# Supremum and infimum in lattices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, supremum-and-infimum

If $(L, \vee, \wedge)$ be a lattice.  Then we know that we can define an order on L by requiring $a \preceq b$ iff $a \wedge b = a$..

> How can I show that any two elements in L say $x$ and $y$ have a supremum ( and an infimum )?

I can show that  $w = x \vee y$ acts as upper bound for $x$ and $y$ .. but lack arguments to show that $w$ is the least upper bound for $x$ and $y$.

Kindly help me out ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $a\preceq b$ can also be described as $a\vee b=b$.

Since $a\preceq a\vee b$ and $b\preceq a\vee b$ we can recognize
in $a\vee b$ an upper bound of $a$ and $b$.

If $a\preceq c$ and $b\preceq c$ then $c\vee\left(a\vee b\right)=\left(c\vee a\right)\vee b=c\vee b=c$
showing that $a\vee b\preceq c$.

This proves that $a\vee b$ serves as least upper bound of $a$ and $b$.